# Apply a function to a `pandas.Series` and output `pandas.Series` with `pandas.MultiIndex` instead of `pandas.DataFrame`

Tags: pandas, multi-index

EDIT: I have reworked the example by adding more complexity to capture the nuances of the question I'm posing (as suggested by @cs95). This is a completely made up example.

I am running

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
```

```
'1.5.3'
```

I have an elaborate `pd.Series`:

```py
s = pd.Series(
    data=[1, 2, 3],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        pd.Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], name='Letter'),
        pd.CategoricalIndex(['Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat2'], name='Category'),
    ]),
    name='MyData',
    dtype=pd.Int64Dtype(),
)
s
```

```
Letter  Category
a       Cat1        1
b       Cat1        2
c       Cat2        3
Name: MyData, dtype: Int64
```

and an elaborate function which takes an integer and returns a `pd.Series`:

```py
def f(x: int) -> pd.Series:
    assert 1 <= x and x <= 9
    mi = (
        pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
            pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=x + 1, name='Number'),
            pd.date_range(start=f'2020-01-0{x}', periods=x, freq='B', name='Date'),
        ])
    )
    return pd.Series(
        data=mi.get_level_values('Number') + mi.get_level_values('Date').day,
        index=mi,
        name='NumberPlusDate',
        dtype=pd.Int64Dtype(),
    )
f(3)
```

```
Number  Date      
1       2020-01-03     4
2       2020-01-06     8
3       2020-01-07    10
Name: NumberPlusDate, dtype: Int64
```

I would like to apply `f` (elementwise) to `s`. Doing so should result in an object with a total of four index levels. One possibility is

```py
result = s.apply(f)
result
```

```
Number                   1                     2          1          2          3
Date            2020-01-01 2020-01-02 2020-01-03 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-07
Letter Category                                                                  
a      Cat1              2       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
b      Cat1           <NA>          3          5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
c      Cat2           <NA>       <NA>       <NA>          4          8         10
```

This generates a `pd.DataFrame` (a square data structure) containing `pd.NA`. Strangely enough, the `Int64` dtype was lost:

```py
result.dtypes
```

```
Number  Date      
1       2020-01-01    object
        2020-01-02    object
2       2020-01-03    object
1       2020-01-03    object
2       2020-01-06    object
3       2020-01-07    object
dtype: object
```

**Problem**: The square nature of the `pd.DataFrame` means that with longer inputs, the output might not fit in memory (due to too many `NA`s being generated). This could possibly be addressed by using spares data types. I would anyway prefer the output to be a `pd.Series` with a `pd.MultiIndex`, like this

```py
result.stack(result.columns.names)
```

```
Letter  Category  Number  Date      
a       Cat1      1       2020-01-01     2
b       Cat1      1       2020-01-02     3
                  2       2020-01-03     5
c       Cat2      1       2020-01-03     4
                  2       2020-01-06     8
                  3       2020-01-07    10
```

The only way I know how to stay within `pd.Series` the entire time is to go via `s.groupby` like this:

```
desired_result = s.groupby(s.index.names).apply(lambda g: f(g.item()))
desired_result
```

```
Letter  Category  Number  Date      
a       Cat1      1       2020-01-01     2
b       Cat1      1       2020-01-02     3
                  2       2020-01-03     5
c       Cat2      1       2020-01-03     4
                  2       2020-01-06     8
                  3       2020-01-07    10
Name: MyData, dtype: Int64
```

Note that this preserves the `Int64` dtype and (most of) the index properties, like the names of the levels and the categories of the categorical index.

**Question**: Is going via `groupby` the recommended way? I often keep all my data within `pd.Series` objects with `pd.MultiIndex` and never work with `pd.DataFrame`. How can I apply a function elementwise without ever instantiating a `pd.DataFrame` and retain all the intricacies of my index structures?

Comment: If the value `123` is a constant value, you can directly create the multiindex without using apply.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm trying to apply a general `pd.Series`-valued function `f`. The example above is trivial and chosen to highlight the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Series directly using [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and the `Series` constructor:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10, 20])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat(s.index, len(a)),
                                 (s.to_numpy()[:,None]+a).ravel()])

out = pd.Series(123, index=idx, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Output:

```
Letter    
a       11    123
        21    123
b       12    123
        22    123
c       13    123
        23    123
dtype: Int64
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but my question is not so much about constructing a  desired Series, it's about manipulating an existing Series.

In general I have some Series `s` and I'm doing all kinds of stuff with it. Suddenly I want to apply a function `f` and all I know is that this function `f` returns Series objects with some particular common Index-structure.

Comment: I forgot to say thanks for having look at my question. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with a illustrative more example.